# JavaScript no suma se agrega al lado el numero cuando debería sumar

Tags: javascript, php

Yo otra vez, con el otro problema me ayudo Cris223511.dev, ahora me di cuenta de un problema mas raro, resulta que se yo empiezo a llenar el formulario de arriba para abajo todo joya se suma todo, pero si de casualidad me equivoque en el primer numero por decir puse 1 billete de 1000 y eran 3, en el resultado1 me pone junto, osea cuando el valor total era 2000 y yo cambie el primer valor que tenia 1 billete de 1000 ahora puse 2 billetes de 1000 en resultado1 no me suma me muestra uno al lado del otro asi; 20001000, osea eran 2000 y se puso al lado 1000 no entiendo porque si esta todo bien las variables y esta la suma de los 3 campos en las 3 funciones.

```js
function Suma1() {
    var billetes1 = document.calculadora.billetes1.value;
    var billetes2 = document.calculadora.billetes2.value;
    var billetes3 = document.calculadora.billetes3.value;
    var billetes4 = document.calculadora.billetes4.value;
    var billetes5 = document.calculadora.billetes5.value;
    var billetes6 = document.calculadora.billetes6.value;
    var billetes7 = document.calculadora.billetes7.value;
    var billetes8 = document.calculadora.billetes8.value;
    var billetes9 = document.calculadora.billetes9.value;
    var billetes10 = document.calculadora.billetes10.value;
    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

   var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
    billetes1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes1);
    billetes2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes2);
    billetes3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes3)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes3);
    billetes4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes4)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes4);
    billetes5 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes5)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes5);
    billetes6 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes6)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes6);
    billetes7 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes7)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes7);
    billetes8 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes8)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes8);
    billetes9 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes9)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes9);
    billetes10 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes10)))? 0 : parseFloat(billetes10);
    Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
    resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

    document.calculadora.Rbilletes1.value = billetes1 * 1000;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes2.value = billetes2 * 500;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes3.value = billetes3 * 200;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes4.value = billetes4 * 100;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes5.value = billetes5 * 50;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes6.value = billetes6 * 20;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes7.value = billetes7 * 10;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes8.value = billetes8 * 5;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes9.value = billetes9 * 2;
    document.calculadora.Rbilletes10.value = billetes10 * 1;

    var Rbilletes1 = billetes1 * 1000;
    var Rbilletes2 = billetes2 * 500;
    var Rbilletes3 = billetes3 * 200;
    var Rbilletes4 = billetes4 * 100;
    var Rbilletes5 = billetes5 * 50;
    var Rbilletes6 = billetes6 * 20;
    var Rbilletes7 = billetes7 * 10;
    var Rbilletes8 = billetes8 * 5;
    var Rbilletes9 = billetes9 * 2;
    var Rbilletes10 = billetes10 * 1;

        Rbilletestotal = Rbilletes1 + Rbilletes2 + Rbilletes3 + Rbilletes4 + Rbilletes5 + Rbilletes6 + Rbilletes7 + Rbilletes8 + Rbilletes9 + Rbilletes10;
        resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + arqueoTotal + comprobantetotal; // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

        document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value = Rbilletestotal;
        document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

function Suma2() {
    var arqueoMonto1 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto1.value;
    var arqueoMonto2 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto2.value;
    var arqueoMonto3 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto3.value;
    var arqueoMonto4 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto4.value;
    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

    var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
    arqueoMonto1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto1);
    arqueoMonto2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto2);
    arqueoMonto3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto3))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto3);
    arqueoMonto4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto4))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto4);
    arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
    Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
    resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

    arqueoTotal = arqueoMonto1 + arqueoMonto2 + arqueoMonto3 + arqueoMonto4;
    resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + arqueoTotal + comprobantetotal; // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

    document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value = arqueoTotal;
    document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

function Suma3() {
    var comprobantemonto1 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto1.value;
    var comprobantemonto2 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto2.value;
    var comprobantemonto3 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto3.value;
    var comprobantemonto4 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto4.value;

    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

    var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
    comprobantemonto1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto1);
    comprobantemonto2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto2);
    comprobantemonto3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto3))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto3);
    comprobantemonto4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto4))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto4);
    Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
    arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
    comprobantetotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantetotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantetotal);
    resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

    comprobantetotal = comprobantemonto1 + comprobantemonto2 + comprobantemonto3 + comprobantemonto4;
    resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + arqueoTotal + comprobantetotal; // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

    document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value = comprobantetotal;
    document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" name="calculadora" method="post" action="gracias.php" novalidate><!--END ROW-->
        <!-- ################## ARQUEO DE EFECTIVO #########################-->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Efectivo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes1" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">1000</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes1" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes2" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">500</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes2" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes3" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">200</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes3" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes4" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">100</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes4" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes5" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">50</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes5" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes6" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">20</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes6" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes7" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">10</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes7" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes8" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">5</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes8" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes9" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">2</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes9" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="28%" align="right">
        <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes10" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
        </td>
        <td width="6%" align="right">1</td>
        <td width="66%">
        <input type="number" name="Rbilletes10" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Total</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Rbilletestotal" id="Rbilletestotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--##################   ARQUEO DE VALORES ########################-->
        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Valores</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td width="18%">Monto</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="18%">
          <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto1" onKeyUp="Suma2()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="18%">
          <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto2" onKeyUp="Suma2()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="18%">
          <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto3" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto3" onKeyUp="Suma2()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="18%">
          <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto4" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto4" onKeyUp="Suma2()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" name="arqueoTotal" id="arqueoTotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--##########  ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES ###########-->
        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Comprobantes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">Monto</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" name="comprobantemonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto1" onKeyUp="Suma3()"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" name="comprobantemonto2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto6" onKeyUp="Suma3()"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" name="comprobantemonto3" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto7" onKeyUp="Suma3()"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto4" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto4" onKeyUp="Suma3()"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" name="comprobantetotal" id="comprobantetotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--###### FIN DE ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES #######-->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="title-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped" width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="312"><strong>TOTAL GENERAL:</strong></td>
          <td width="198"><input type="number" name="resultado1" step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' id="resultado1" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
  </form>
```

La idea es que en el input resultado1 vaya sumando todos los otros resultados, y cuando se quite o se agregue un numero cualquiera afecte al resultado1, cosa que no esta sucediendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer **`typeof()`** de las variables de los totales de cada sección (en tu función **`Suma1()`**)

```
console.log("Suma1 tengo");
console.log("Rbilletestotal =>", typeof (Rbilletestotal));
console.log("arqueoTotal =>", typeof (arqueoTotal));
console.log("comprobantetotal =>", typeof (comprobantetotal));
```

Noté que `arqueoTotal` y `comprobantetotal` eran strings, por lo que estás concatenando la cadena al intentar sumar los totales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución sería agregar las siguientes validaciones al igual que hacías en las otras funciones de abajo (`Suma2()` y `Suma3()`) a tus dos totales, así:

```
Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
comprobantetotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantetotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantetotal);
```

Y ya con esto las variables serán **números** y no **strings**, de la cual tu suma ya funcionaría.

---

Código completo:

```js
function Suma1() {
    var billetes1 = document.calculadora.billetes1.value;
    var billetes2 = document.calculadora.billetes2.value;
    var billetes3 = document.calculadora.billetes3.value;
    var billetes4 = document.calculadora.billetes4.value;
    var billetes5 = document.calculadora.billetes5.value;
    var billetes6 = document.calculadora.billetes6.value;
    var billetes7 = document.calculadora.billetes7.value;
    var billetes8 = document.calculadora.billetes8.value;
    var billetes9 = document.calculadora.billetes9.value;
    var billetes10 = document.calculadora.billetes10.value;
    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

    var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
        billetes1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes1);
        billetes2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes2);
        billetes3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes3))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes3);
        billetes4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes4))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes4);
        billetes5 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes5))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes5);
        billetes6 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes6))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes6);
        billetes7 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes7))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes7);
        billetes8 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes8))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes8);
        billetes9 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes9))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes9);
        billetes10 = (isNaN(parseFloat(billetes10))) ? 0 : parseFloat(billetes10);
        Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
        arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
        comprobantetotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantetotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantetotal);
        resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

        document.calculadora.Rbilletes1.value = billetes1 * 1000;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes2.value = billetes2 * 500;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes3.value = billetes3 * 200;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes4.value = billetes4 * 100;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes5.value = billetes5 * 50;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes6.value = billetes6 * 20;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes7.value = billetes7 * 10;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes8.value = billetes8 * 5;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes9.value = billetes9 * 2;
        document.calculadora.Rbilletes10.value = billetes10 * 1;

        var Rbilletes1 = billetes1 * 1000;
        var Rbilletes2 = billetes2 * 500;
        var Rbilletes3 = billetes3 * 200;
        var Rbilletes4 = billetes4 * 100;
        var Rbilletes5 = billetes5 * 50;
        var Rbilletes6 = billetes6 * 20;
        var Rbilletes7 = billetes7 * 10;
        var Rbilletes8 = billetes8 * 5;
        var Rbilletes9 = billetes9 * 2;
        var Rbilletes10 = billetes10 * 1;

        Rbilletestotal = Rbilletes1 + Rbilletes2 + Rbilletes3 + Rbilletes4 + Rbilletes5 + Rbilletes6 + Rbilletes7 + Rbilletes8 + Rbilletes9 + Rbilletes10;
        resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + Number(arqueoTotal) + Number(comprobantetotal); // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

        // console.log("Suma1 tengo");
        // console.log("Rbilletestotal =>", typeof (Rbilletestotal));
        // console.log("arqueoTotal =>", typeof (arqueoTotal));
        // console.log("comprobantetotal =>", typeof (comprobantetotal));

        document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value = Rbilletestotal;
        document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

function Suma2() {
    var arqueoMonto1 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto1.value;
    var arqueoMonto2 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto2.value;
    var arqueoMonto3 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto3.value;
    var arqueoMonto4 = document.calculadora.arqueoMonto4.value;
    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

    var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
        arqueoMonto1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto1);
        arqueoMonto2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto2);
        arqueoMonto3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto3))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto3);
        arqueoMonto4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoMonto4))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoMonto4);
        Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
        arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
        comprobantetotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantetotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantetotal);
        resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

        arqueoTotal = arqueoMonto1 + arqueoMonto2 + arqueoMonto3 + arqueoMonto4;
        resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + arqueoTotal + comprobantetotal; // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

        // console.log("Rbilletestotal =>", typeof (Rbilletestotal));
        // console.log("arqueoTotal =>", typeof (arqueoTotal));
        // console.log("comprobantetotal =>", typeof (comprobantetotal));

        document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value = arqueoTotal;
        document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

function Suma3() {
    var comprobantemonto1 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto1.value;
    var comprobantemonto2 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto2.value;
    var comprobantemonto3 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto3.value;
    var comprobantemonto4 = document.calculadora.comprobantemonto4.value;

    var Rbilletestotal = document.calculadora.Rbilletestotal.value; // total arqueo de efectivo
    var arqueoTotal = document.calculadora.arqueoTotal.value; // total arqueo de valores
    var comprobantetotal = document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value; // total arqueo de comprobantes

    var resultado1 = 0; // total final

    try {
        comprobantemonto1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto1);
        comprobantemonto2 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto2))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto2);
        comprobantemonto3 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto3))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto3);
        comprobantemonto4 = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantemonto4))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantemonto4);
        Rbilletestotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(Rbilletestotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(Rbilletestotal);
        arqueoTotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(arqueoTotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(arqueoTotal);
        comprobantetotal = (isNaN(parseFloat(comprobantetotal))) ? 0 : parseFloat(comprobantetotal);
        resultado1 = (isNaN(parseFloat(resultado1))) ? 0 : parseFloat(resultado1);

        comprobantetotal = comprobantemonto1 + comprobantemonto2 + comprobantemonto3 + comprobantemonto4;
        resultado1 = Rbilletestotal + arqueoTotal + comprobantetotal; // siempre sumo a los 3 totales

        // console.log("Rbilletestotal =>", typeof (Rbilletestotal));
        // console.log("arqueoTotal =>", typeof (arqueoTotal));
        // console.log("comprobantetotal =>", typeof (comprobantetotal));

        document.calculadora.comprobantetotal.value = comprobantetotal;
        document.calculadora.resultado1.value = resultado1;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="needs-validation" name="calculadora" method="post" action="gracias.php" novalidate>
  <!-- ################## ARQUEO DE EFECTIVO #########################-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Efectivo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes1" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">1000</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes1" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes2" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">500</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes2" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes3" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">200</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes3" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes4" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">100</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes4" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes5" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">50</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes5" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes6" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">20</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes6" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes7" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">10</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes7" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes8" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">5</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes8" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes9" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">2</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes9" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="28%" align="right">
            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes10" value='' onKeyUp="Suma1()">
          </td>
          <td width="6%" align="right">1</td>
          <td width="66%">
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes10" value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">Total</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="Rbilletestotal" id="Rbilletestotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--##################   ARQUEO DE VALORES ########################-->
  <hr class="my-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Valores</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">Monto</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto1" onKeyUp="Suma2()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto2" onKeyUp="Suma2()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto3" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto3" onKeyUp="Suma2()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto4" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto4" onKeyUp="Suma2()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="arqueoTotal" id="arqueoTotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--##########  ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES ###########-->
  <hr class="my-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Comprobantes</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">Monto</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto1" onKeyUp="Suma3()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto6" onKeyUp="Suma3()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto3" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto7" onKeyUp="Suma3()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%">
            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto4" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto4" onKeyUp="Suma3()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="comprobantetotal" id="comprobantetotal" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--###### FIN DE ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES #######-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-primary"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped" width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="312"><strong>TOTAL GENERAL:</strong></td>
          <td width="198">
            <input type="number" name="resultado1" step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' id="resultado1" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en **[éste enlace](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/OJwRLrg)**.

Comment: Gracias Cris, como siempre me salvando las pasa ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema claramente es porque en algún lado no estas convirtiendo el `input.value` a `Number`. Yo no fui capaz de comprender tú código así que hice el mío que es bastante más corto y genérico, espero te sirva:

```js
function Suma1(valor, factor, totalInput) {
    let valorNum = Number(valor);
    if (valorNum) {
        totalInput.value = factor * valor;
    }
    else {
        totalInput.value = 0;
    }
    calcularTotalPorClase(".Rbilletes",Rbilletestotal);
    calcularTotalPorClase(".total",resultado1);
}
function calcularTotalPorClase(clase,input) {
    let total = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll(clase).forEach(e => total += Number(e.value));
    input.value = total;

}
function Suma2() {
    calcularTotalPorClase(".arqueoMonto", arqueoTotal);
    calcularTotalPorClase(".total",resultado1);
}
function Suma3() {
    calcularTotalPorClase(".comprobantemonto", comprobantetotal);
    calcularTotalPorClase(".total",resultado1);
}
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" name="calculadora" method="post" action="gracias.php" novalidate>
        <!--END ROW-->
        <!-- ################## ARQUEO DE EFECTIVO #########################-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Efectivo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="tablaArqueo" class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="28%" align="right">
                            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes1" value='' oninput="Suma1(this.value,1000,Rbilletes1)">
                        </td>
                        <td width="6%" align="right">1000</td>
                        <td width="66%">
                            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="Rbilletes1" class="Rbilletes" disabled>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="28%" align="right">
                            <input style="width: 60px; float: right; text-align: center" type="number" name="billetes2" value='' oninput="Suma1(this.value,500,Rbilletes2)">
                        </td>
                        <td width="6%" align="right">500</td>
                        <td width="66%">
                            <input type="number" name="Rbilletes2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="Rbilletes2" class="Rbilletes" disabled>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right">Total</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="Rbilletestotal" id="Rbilletestotal" class="total" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--##################   ARQUEO DE VALORES ########################-->
        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Valores</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="18%">Monto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="18%">
                            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto1" class="arqueoMonto" oninput="Suma2()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="18%">
                            <input type="number" name="arqueoMonto2" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="arqueoMonto2" class="arqueoMonto" oninput="Suma2()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="number" name="arqueoTotal" id="arqueoTotal" class="total" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--##########  ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES ###########-->
        <hr class="my-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-primary">Arqueo de Comprobantes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped" width="67%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="18%">Monto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="number" name="comprobantemonto1" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto1" class="comprobantemonto" oninput="Suma3()"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="18%">
                            <input type="number" name="comprobantemonto4" value='' placeholder="0.00" id="comprobantemonto4" class="comprobantemonto" oninput="Suma3()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="number" name="comprobantetotal" id="comprobantetotal" class="total" step='0.01' value='' placeholder="0.00" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--###### FIN DE ARQUEO DE COMPROBANTES #######-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-primary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped" width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="312"><strong>TOTAL GENERAL:</strong></td>
                        <td width="198"><input type="number" name="resultado1" step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' id="resultado1" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Consideraciones

1.- Eliminé algunas filas para hacer un ejemplo algo más corto tu debes completaras

2.- Cambié los eventos `onkeyup` por `oninput` que me parece mejor para tu caso, ahora el evento funciona si mueves haces click en los botones up/down e incluso si pegas un valor

3.- Debes fijarte que he agregado Id's y clases a los inputs. Cuando agregues las nuevas filas debes seguir la nomenclatura (creo que es clara). El javascript no es necesario modificarlo

4.- La idea general es agrupar conceptos por clases y luego sumar, para esto está la función `calcularTotalPorClase`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Yussef, me gusto el oninput, ahora si suma tambien con la flechita. Gracias totales!!!!!